# Horizontally aligning elements in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align three elements in a div in such a way that the image is inline with h1 while the p tag is beneath the h1 tag.

```css
.valign{
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
.banner{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="banner" style="display:flex">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="valign">
          <img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 150px;width: 150px">
          <h1>Anirudh Sharma</h1>
          <p>This is my portfolio</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image for reference:
[This is how the elements must be arranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3IYc.jpg)

This is how the elements are looking right now:
[This is a screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmPD9.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? I think not.

Comment: Tried positioning it with an <ul> inline property but asn't effective. @DeepakKamat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="banner" style="display:flex">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="valign">
                    <div class="float-xs-left float-sm-left float-md-left">
                    <img src="img/logo.png"></div>
                    <div class="float-xs-left float-sm-left float-md-left">
                    <h1>Anirudh Sharma</h1>
                    <p>This is my portfolio</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the class value for float is based on bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this html

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="banner" style="display:flex">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="valign">
                        <div style="float:left">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 150px;width: 150px"></div>
                        <div style="float:left">
                        <h1>Anirudh Sharma</h1>
                        <p>This is my portfolio</p></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floats, Bootstrap provides `pull-left` and `pull-right` helper classes, so use it on the two parts of your layout to have them side-by-by.

You need to add some margins here and there to make it look good.

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="banner" style="display:flex">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="valign">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 150px;width: 150px">
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <h1>Anirudh Sharma</h1>
                                <p>This is my portfolio</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n8o1w3cq/